# Use Docker to Distribute CLI Application

Tags: docker

I'm somewhat new to Docker. I would like to be able to use Docker to distribute a CLI program, but run the program normally once it has been installed. To be specific, after running `docker build` on the system, I need to be able to simply run `my-program` in the terminal, not `docker run my-program`. How can I do this?

I tried something with a Makefile which runs `docker build -t my-program .` and then writes a shell script to `~/.local/bin/` called `my-program` that runs `docker run my-program`, but this adds another container every time I run the script.

EDIT: I realize is the expected behavior of `docker run`, but it does not work for my use-case.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd encourage you to use a simpler distribution mechanism for this.  This approach requires installing Docker, which the target system may not necessarily have; it frequently requires administrator permissions to run; and it can't directly access host files or devices without special setup.  Using a language- or distribution-native packaging system will work more consistently for the end user.

Comment: I would, but I'm using Common LISP (compiled with SBCL) as well as special Quicklisp and Buildapp setup. I'd rather not force the user to perform ~20 steps (yes that's an accurate estimate) just to install my program.

Comment: But I see what you mean about file access... Hmm... Perhaps I will try to distribute with `apt`, `pacman`, etc instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep your script, add the remove flag `--rm` to the `docker run` command. The remove flag removes the container automatically after the entry-point process has exit.

Additionally, I would personally prefer an `alias` for this. Simply add something like this example `alias my-program="docker run --rm my-program"` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` file. This even has the advantage that all other parameters after the alias (`my-program param1 param2`) are automatically forwarded to the entry-point of your image without any additional effort.

Comment: The `--rm` flag works! Thanks! About `alias` vs a script, I prefer using a script so that the Makefile can perform *all* installation, making it completely hands-off for the end-user. I can simply use `$*` to pass arguments to the `docker run` command inside the script.

Comment: And using a script also allows the Makefile to perform complete uninstallation.